# else statement always run even the answer is true

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

tnx! it works. but when i tried to add another object named, p1_2 and add the "trace" thing to the code,
it goes back to the same problem.

```
p1_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    question.text = "shape?";
}
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickss);
function onClickss(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    trace("ans.text = "+ans.text); 
    if (ans.text == "circle")
{
    p1_1.visible = false;
}
else
{
    gotoAndStop(6);
}

}




p1_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick2);
function onClick2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    question.text = "Color?";
}
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickss2);
function onClickss2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("ans.text = "+ans.text);
if (ans.text == "red")
{
    p1_2.visible = false;
}
else
{
    gotoAndStop(6);
}

}
```

what should i do.? do i nid to seperate p1_2 in another frame
and make another inputtextfield for it? 
im planning to add 5 objects on the stage. until p1_5. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Before the line...

```
if(ans.text == "circle") {
```

...add:

```
trace("ans.text = "+ans.text);
```

Clicking the submit button will trace the actual value of ans.text to the output panel when you test your movie in Flash. If you get a null reference error then ans has not been instantiated. Otherwise, knowing the actual value of ans.text should point you in the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: They would actually be getting a null ref error already, since `ans.text` is already being evaluated. if-else conditionals do not behave like a try...catch and will error out.

Comment: True, but still; knowing the text value in ans will probably point out what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I was just pointing out that that part of your answer was incorrect.

Comment: so what conditional statement is the best to use for this? im sorry im  just a newbie on flash and as3. :/

Comment: From the details you provide it's not clear what kind of object 'ans' is. Is it a TextField? If so, you'll need to make sure the user has the opportunity to input their answer into the TextField before submitting, or, if the TextField text is empty when submit is clicked (ans.text = "") prompting the user to enter an answer. So, before checking if an answer is useful, check if any answer has been entered.